# add leading zeros to decimal point in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, math, double

I want to add leading zeros to my double number in flutter but only if if number has one decimal point, example:

user input => formatted value

3.4 => 3.04

3.40 => 3.4 (or 3.40, don't really matter)

I know I can convert this to string, split it and then do some calculations but I can't find any one liner method and I'm pretty sure there should be one

Comment: ...why? Numbers aren't strings, so when you're talking about 3.4 and 3.40, those are _the same number_, turned into strings using two different string formatting rules. If you just want to inject a zero into the string representation, then do that (check for a `.` followed by `a digit` and insert the character `0`). But if you want to change the _number_, then this is an impossible math problem because 3.4 and 3.40 are _the same number_ but you want two different outputs for the same input.

Comment: `3.4` is not equal to `3.04` and `3.40` is equal to `3.4`, Do you still want to convert *3.4 => 3.04*?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to fix your decimal points to two decimals

```
#.##
3.4 => 3.40
3.04 => 3.04
5.2 => 5.20
```

you can do the following by adding:

```
yourDoubleVariable.toStringAsFixed(2);
```